# Access Retropie SSH from USB in Raspberry Pi Zero?

Tags: usb, ssh, retropie

I have a raspberry pi zero without wireless and I need to log into Retropie SSH, but I have no other means of accessing it than through USB. I've tried following a tutorial before about using SSH through USB, but it didn't work. What should I do in order to be able to use Raspberry Pi Zero Retropie SSH through USB?

Solution:

Remember to enable SSH. When trying to connect, use the following data:

Host: retropie

User: pi

Password: raspberry

---

Reference: https://retropie.org.uk/docs/SSH/

Comment: I couldn't connect, although I settle everything right, using PuTTY and all.

Comment: Where did I claim I did everything? I just said that the USB is my only option. What I did was editing some files to allow SSH through USB and then I tried to connect from PuTTY, with no luck.

Comment: That part? I was referring to the instructions of that tutorial I was following.

Comment: Finally managed to connect through USB. I didn't provide you with the tutorial before because I couldn't find the url, but this tutorial is the same thing, it has the same steps: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/directly-connect-raspberry-pi-without-internet
There where two problems, first, I had to enable SSH from Retropie settings, second, the data I was using to connect was wrong. Found the correct data here: https://retropie.org.uk/docs/SSH/
Host: retropie
User: Pi
Password: Raspberry